# How show waypoints in a map from DirectionFinder

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to build an app that it shows start location, end location and waypoints in the map, with distance and time travel in text view, I call the waypoints in the `DirectionFinder.java`, but it not work; How I do for invoking waypoints from since JSON, like the file it calls to `end_location` and `start_location`

This is **DirectionFinder.java**

```
public class DirectionFinder {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AAAAAAA";
    private DirectionFinderListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String waypoints;


    public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, String destination, String waypoints) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.waypoints = waypoints;

    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();
        new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl());
    }

    private String createUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");
        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "utf-8");
        String urlWaypoints = URLEncoder.encode(waypoints, "utf-8");


        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination + "&waypoints=optimize:true" + urlWaypoints + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");


            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng(
                    lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d
            ));
        }

        return decoded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=18.519513,73.868315&destination=18.518496,73.879259&waypoints=18.520561,73.872435|18.519254,73.876614|18.52152,73.877327|18.52019,73.879935&travelmode=driving");
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
  intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
      try {
            startActivity(intent);
          } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
           try {
               Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
               startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException innerEx) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
 }
```

**Following are reference link:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

**output**

[image]